# Splitting a boolean search string into its constituent parts / counting what causes SQL SELECT matches

Tags: php, mysql, regex

As per [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599151/adding-a-term-to-each-item-of-a-boolean-query-in-php-reg-exp), a software recruiter can enter a boolean text string, ***such as*** `C++ AND ((UML OR Python) OR (not Perl))`, which I will translate to `SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE skill=C++ AND ((skill=UML OR skill=Python) OR (not skill=Perl))`.

(I highlighted ***such as*** because some answers seem to think that  I am only interested in this query. It is only an example. I seek a generic solution, coded in PHP. Maybe a regex? Just some code which finds every sub-term of a query, so that I can query the sub-terms individually.)

I could like to `COUNT(*)` the number of hits, but I would also be very interested to know how much each "sub-clause" (if that's the correct term) of the query contributed to the result.

E.g. there might have been 200 candidates with C++, but 50 were not suitable because they have neither UML nor Python experience.

So, using either PHP (and rexex?) or MySql, how can I break that down to see which parts of the search term contribute to the result?

I.e, break down `skill=C++ AND ((skill=UML OR skill=Python) OR (not skill=Perl))` into `COUNT(*) WHERE skill=C++` and  `COUNT (*) WHERE (skill=UML OR skill=Python), etc

I don't know if MySQL has some sort of `EXPLAIN` for this, but suspect not, so that I will have to break out the `SELECT` as described and `COUNT` each sub-clause separately.

Comment: You could just run a separate query on the individual conditions that you're interested in, right?

Comment: Lolx. Yes, but that's the point of the question - how to break a complex query down into its constituent conditions?

Comment: You will need to write a parser. This is not a one-evening-task.

Comment: This is a somewhat offtopic and perhaps stupid question, but Why somebody would want a person *not* having experience on some subject?

Comment: show us what you have tried so we can help you. we are not here to write the code for you

Comment: Your best bet is a mapping table with each skill being on a separate record and changing your input to something more standard like `C++ UML Python -Perl` where the `-` implies NOT. This is used by most search engines and most users understand it. Forcing the user to create input like `C++ AND ((UML OR Python) OR (not Perl))` will create a terrible user experience and most users would not understand it. You could then easily check for if a record in your table matches each criteria by generating some `MAX(skill = 'criteria') and adding them together to see if it matches the number of criteria.

Comment: Sorry, but I was asked for that syntax by the end user. Probably because it is google search syntax

Comment: @Mawg, the bounty ends tomorrow :) Have you had a chance to evaluate the answers? (I edited mine a day ago or so for adding the boolean split, just in case you didn't notice it)

Comment: Your question is interesting for me I noticed that you want regex and only php. anyway I have answered it and this my first time to write complete script as answer in stackoverflow or any other forum .I didn't test script but it should work. Your question is good but not suitable for this community as members here for help and general ideas not for writing scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a method for splitting the conditions. However we cannot split ANDs and ORs as equal because **ANDs have higher priority over ORs**.

So in an example like this:

```
Cond1 AND Cond2 OR Cond3
```

We cannot split by `AND|OR` because we would be missing `Cond1 AND Cond2` as a whole.

So the first thing to do is add extra parenthesis (with regexes) where needed so that the following algorithm will split correctly the conditions. In the previous example, It would be `(Cond1 AND Cond2) OR Cond3`.

Once setup, we use a regex to fetch conditions for the current Level. We need to use recursive regular expressions in order to detect opening/closing parenthesis.

Every conditions is stored on an array and then sent to be processed (recursively). This is because some conditions may be complex and have nested conditions.

All this conditions and sub-conditions are being stored on the array.

Once you have all the conditions (and sub-conditions) you have two alternatives to mount the SQL.

The first option would be a single query with no WHERE clause and one SUM for every condition. This is probably best if the are no that many rows on the table

The second option is running multiple `SELECT count(*)` queries with all the conditions.

I leave here the php code. I also added an option to customize the maximum number of nest levels when splitting the conditions.

You have a demo on **Ideone**, [here](https://www.ideone.com/mIMXPY).

```
<?php

$conditions = 'C++ AND ((UML OR Python) OR (not Perl))';

// Other tests...
//$conditions = "C++ AND Python OR Perl";
//$conditions = "C++ AND Python OR Perl OR (Perl AND (Ruby AND Docker AND (Lisp OR (C++ AND Ada) AND Java)))";

///////// CONFIGURATION /////////
$maxNest = 0; // Set to 0 for unlimited nest levels
/////////////////////////////////

print "Original Input:\n";
print $conditions . "\n\n";

// Add implicit parenthesis...
// For example: `A AND B OR C` should be: `(A AND B) OR C`
$addParenthesis = '/(?|(((?:\bNOT\b\s*+)?+[^)(\s]++|(?:\bNOT\b\s*+)?+[(](?:\s*+(?2)\s*+)*+[)])(?:\s*+\bAND\b\s*+((?2)))++)(?=\s*+\bOR\b\s*+)|\s*+\bOR\b\s*+\K((?1)))/im';
while (preg_match($addParenthesis, $conditions)) {
  $conditions = preg_replace($addParenthesis, '(\1)', $conditions);
}

print "Input after adding implicit parenthesis (if needed):\n";
print $conditions . "\n\n";

// Optional cleanup: Remove useless NOT () parenthesis
$conditions = preg_replace('/[(]\s*((?:NOT\s*)?+(\S+))\s*[)]/i', '\1', $conditions);

// Optional cleanup: Remove useless NOT NOT...
$conditions = preg_replace('/\bNOT\s+NOT\b/i', '', $conditions);

$list_conditions = [$conditions];

function split_conditions($input, $level = 0) {
  global $list_conditions, $maxNest;

  if ($maxNest > 0 && $level >= $maxNest) { return; }

  // If it is a logic operator, skip
  if ( preg_match('/^\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*$/i', $input) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Add condition to the list:
  array_push($list_conditions, $input);

  // Don't go on if this is a single filter
  if ( preg_match('/^\s*(?:NOT\s+)?+[^)(\s]+\s*$/i', $input) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Remove parenthesis (if exists) before evaluating sub expressions
  // Do this only for level > 0. Level 0 is not guaranteed to have
  // sorrounding parenthesis, so It may remove wanted parenthesis 
  // such in this expression: `(Cond1 AND Cond2) OR (Cond3 AND Cond4)`
  if ($level > 0) {
    $input = preg_replace('/^\s*(?:NOT\b\s*)?+[(](.*)[)]\s*$/i', '\1', $input);
  }

  // Fetch all sub-conditions at current level:
  $next_conds = '/((?:\bNOT\b\s*+)?+[^)(\s]++|(?:\bNOT\b\s*+)?+[(](?:\s*+(?1)\s*+)*+[)])/i';
  preg_match_all($next_conds, $input, $matches);

  // Evaluate subexpressions
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    split_conditions($match, $level + 1);
  }
}

split_conditions($conditions);

// Trim and remove duplicates
$list_conditions = array_unique(array_map(function($x){
  return preg_replace('/^\s*|\s*$/', '', $x);
}, $list_conditions));

// Add columns
$list_conditions = array_map(function($x){
  return preg_replace('/([^\s()]++)(?<!\bAND\b)(?<!\bOR\b)(?<!\bNOT\b)/i', "skill='$1'", $x);
}, $list_conditions);

print "Just the conditions...\n\n";
print_r($list_conditions);
print "\n\n";

print "Method 1) Single query with multiple SUM\n\n";
$sum_conditions = implode(",\n", array_map(function($x){
  return "    SUM( $x )";
}, $list_conditions));
$sumSQL = "SELECT\n$sum_conditions\nFROM candidates;";
print $sumSQL . "\n\n";

print "Method 2) Multiple queries\n\n";
$queries = implode("\n", array_map(function($x){
  return "SELECT count(*) from candidates WHERE $x;";
}, $list_conditions));
print $queries . "\n\n";
```

Comment: FYI @mawg I changed my answer to give you a code that should be able to split any conditions within any nesting level, and should also take care of AND/OR precedence. The code will also output two options for the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

While not the most elegant solution, the `WITH ROLLUP`Mysql function could be useful. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

In its simplest method, you could write this query to capture unique skills:

```
SELECT skill, COUNT(skill) AS mycount
FROM cands
GROUP BY skill WITH ROLLUP
```

This will return the total count of all skills, with a `NULL` line at the bottom with the total, like this:

```
|skill   |mycount  |
|--------|---------|
|C++     |  2      |
|Java    |  3      |
|Python  |  4      |
|NULL    |  9      |
```

By adding boolean operations, you could obtain a more complex result:

```
SELECT skill, COUNT(skill) AS mycount, SUM(IF(skill='C++' || skill='Python', 1, 0)) AS CorPython
FROM cands
GROUP BY skill WITH ROLLUP
```

With this second option, the `CorPython` column will sum up -- at the last `NULL` line -- the total people with "C or Python". You can make this boolean section as complex are necessary.

```
|skill   |mycount  |CorPython  |
|--------|---------|-----------|
|C++     |  2      |  2        |
|Java    |  3      |  0        |
|Python  |  4      |  4        |
|NULL    |  9      |  6        |   <-- This is the value you want (6)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in MySQL **full-text** search capabilities? The return is automatically ranked with the best matches at the top.

You could create a new column which holds all the **skills** of the candidate. Then a search on that field would give you the ranked results.

[Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
 count(*),
 sum(skill=C++),
 sum(skill=UML),
 sum(skill=Python),
 sum(not skill=Perl)
FROM candidates WHERE TRUE
AND skill=C++
AND (FALSE
  OR (FALSE
       OR skill=UML
       OR skill=Python)
  OR (not skill=Perl)
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: Actually, as OP, I have to say that it does not answer the question. It answers an example I gave in the question, but only a generic solution would be helpful. Perhaps I need to edit the question to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

1. Recompute a table from `SELECT skill, COUNT(*) FROM tbl` and the complements.
2. Provide the full table from step 1; let the recruiter eyeball the list.

To get fancier, simply strip parens, OR, AND from the text string to get the various skills mentioned.  Then display only those.

But neither of these handle `(UML OR Python)` or non-adjacent things like `(C++ and not Perl)`.  Anyway, how many counts would you expect from your example?  There is also `(UML OR Python) AND C++` and several more.

Don't even think of parsing via SQL; use some client language.  Or pose the question to the candidates.

Code hints

In Perl, one might do:

```
$str =~ s{[()]|AND|OR|NOT}{ }ig;
$str =~ s{ +}{ }g;
@skills = split('  ', $str);
```

The PHP code would use `preg_replace` and `explode`, but otherwise be similar.  In your example, `C++ AND ((UML OR Python) OR (not Perl))` would become the array ['C++', 'UML', 'Python', 'Perl']

Answer (score 0):

Hi that's not abig deal watch out

```
$sqlresult =array ('php, html, php, c++, perl');
//that is array result from MySQL and now we need to count every term alone only in php

//now I create this 
function getcount ($word, $paragraphp){
if (preg_match("/$word/i", $paragraph))
    $count = 1;
else
    $count = 0;

return $count;
}

foreach ( $sqlresult as $key ) {
$finalresult = array ();
$finalresult['$key'] += getcount($key, $key);
}

//now retrieve results as following 

$php = " results for php word is $finalresult[php]";
$perl = "results for perl word is $finalresult[perl]";
echo $php;
echo $perl;
```

If you have paragraph with many words so you should convert it to array with explode php function first and start steps as above

In big project that is not suitable you need a good substitute to MySQL 
In this case I suggest  SPHINX search 
After you run query in SPHINX 
Run this query

```
SHOW META;
```

This will give every word in your search with hit count  for more details check this http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-show-meta.html